# Calling jquery in default.aspx

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am new to asp.net, I am trying to add a field "Experience", when user adds company name, from date and to date. for that I am using a , now for that I am using jQuery. to add new columns dynamically i have written the jQuery function, but i am not getting where to add those function, when i run only single column is coming.Please help out how to add jQuery code into ASP.NET below is my function

```
var $lastChar =1, $newRow;
$get_lastID = function(){
    var $id = $('#experience_table tr:last-child td:first-child input').attr("name");
    $lastChar = parseInt($id.substr($id.length - 2), 10);
    $lastChar = $lastChar + 1;
    $newRow = "<tr> \
        <td><input type='text' name='company_name_0"+$lastChar+"' maxlength='255' /></td> \
        <td><input type='text' name='from_0"+$lastChar+"'  /></td> \
        <td><input type='text' name='to_0"+$lastChar+"'  /></td> \
        <td><input type='number' name='Total_exp_0"+$lastChar+"' maxlength='11' /></td> \
        <td><input type='text' name='edit_0"+$lastChar+"' maxlength='255' /></td> \
        <td><input type='button' value='Delete' class='del_ExperienceRow' /></td> \
            </tr>"
    return $newRow;
}
}

$('#add_ExperienceRow').live("click", function(){
    if($('#experience_table tr').size() <= 9){
        $get_lastID();
        $('#experience_table tbody').append($newRow);
    } else {
        alert("Reached Maximum Rows!");
    };
});

$(".del_ExperienceRow").live("click", function(){ 
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    $lastChar = $lastChar-2;
});
```

Comment: jquery version used? the `live()` method is deprecated and removed in jquery 1.9..

Comment: also have you included jQuery library in the project... and any errors in the browser console

Comment: EVen after loads of Googling, I am not getting proper idea to add the Jquery library into project.help me out

Comment: sorry not a .net guy.... it should be easy as far as I know asp.net should have some internal support for jQuery! did you check your browser console what is the error

Comment: it is not showing any error but when I click on Add button, nothing is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your code into this function and script tag

```
<script src="Script/jquery-version.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //Your code goes here
    });
</script>
```

You should also change that .live event handler to .on if you are using recent jQuery version.

Comment: I am still unable to get it :(

Comment: You can always edit your original post to add relevant information.

Comment: Yeah, anyways Eugene I found the solution.Thanks